# SPI Slave Frequency Setup

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, spi

This question is in regards to a configuration where I want to setup a half-duplex SPI bus, with a master outputting a clock at 1MHz.

Does the slave need to know that the clock coming in will be 1MHz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  SPI is a *synchronous* protocol. That means that you transmit the clock as a discrete signal and it is used directly by the receiver to time the reception of the data.  The receiver will have a *maximum* frequency at which it can operate, and some (such as some ADCs) will have a *minimum* frequency to maintain internal accuracy.